# LaTeX output custom commands used in current section

Tags: macros, dramatist

I'm using LaTeX to typeset a drama script. Each character has a self-made command `\<charactername>x` that takes an argument and outputs that text as speech of that character. e.g. `\tomx{Hi, I'm Tom}` means that Tom says "Hi, I'm Tom".

At the beginning of each scene I need a list of characters occuring in this scene. Right now, I'm doing that manually, but it's an error-prone task to keep track which characters say something in that scene, especially if they get crowded. Often, someone is forgotten and I need to triple-check if I included everyone in the character list.

I wonder if it would be possible to tweak my custom speech commands a bit, so that each scene has a variable that keeps a list of characters occuring in that scene, and everytime one of that `\<charactername>x` commands are called, they append the name of the character to that list if it isn't in it already. How could one approach this issue? A MWE might look like this:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\newcommand{\tomx}[1]{
% Alter this command (maybe?) to append "Tom" to the list of
% characters of the scene this command is used in if "Tom" is not yet present.
\textsc{Tom:} #1
}

\begin{document}
\section{In the supermarket}
% Call command here that lists characters in this scene, in this case only tom.
\tomx{Hi, I'm Tom!}
\end{document}
```

It doesn't need to be fast or fancy. Any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, you need some kind of a `label` mechanism, i.e. store where the name is referred and read the information to get information what will come up later on.

Comment: How could I implement that? I haven't done much complex LaTeX coding yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difficulty here is to know which persons will appear later on but the list of characters have to done before.

I am using the `\label` approach here and checking if the label is given, otherwise the person is not listed.

A new person is defined with `\NewPerson{foo}`, which automatically defines `\foox` and adds the code to check for label existence etc.

Now, the Command `\DisplayPersons` loops through all defined persons and stores the local ones, loops again through this smaller list of persons and applies `\displayindividualperson` which can be changed to personal preferences.

The macros `\PostPersonlist` and `\personlistheader` can be configured to provide other styles.

**Note: As with any `\label` based approach at least two runs of compilations are necessary**

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \g_luke_listofpersons_seq
\seq_new:N \l_luke_listofpersons_seq 


\NewDocumentCommand{\addperson}{m}{%
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_luke_listofpersons_seq {#1}
  \seq_gremove_duplicates:N \g_luke_listofpersons_seq
}


\NewDocumentCommand{\addpersonlocal}{m}{%
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \l_luke_listofpersons_seq {#1}
}

\cs_new:Npn \IfPersonCalledAlreadyF #1#2 {%
  \seq_if_in:NnF \l_luke_listofpersons_seq {#1} {#2}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\DisplayPersons}{}{%
  \seq_clear:N \l_luke_listofpersons_seq
  \group_begin:
  \seq_clear:N \l_tmpa_seq
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_luke_listofpersons_seq {%
    \IfRefUndefinedExpandable{##1\thesection}{}{
      \seq_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {\displayindividualperson{##1}}
     }
   }
   \seq_if_empty:NF \l_tmpa_seq {
     \PrePersonList
     \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {,~} 
     \PostPersonList
   }
   \group_end:

}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\PostPersonList}{}{%
  \bigskip%

}

\NewDocumentCommand{\displayindividualperson}{m}{%
  \textbf{#1}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\PrePersonList}{}{%
  {\large \bfseries Persons in Section \thesection}

}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\NewPerson}{m}{%
  % Add this person to the global list
  \addperson{#1}%
  % Now define the personal \...x command 
  \expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\csname #1x\endcsname{+m}{%
    %Check if the person has been called in the local section already
    \IfPersonCalledAlreadyF{#1}{%
      \addpersonlocal{#1}
      % Add the personal to the local list, i.e. per section
      % Check whether the label has been defined already
        \protected@edef\@currentlabel{\thesection.#1}\label{#1\thesection}
    }%
    \textsc{#1:} ##1%
  }% End of the \...x command
}% End of \NewPerson
\makeatother


\NewPerson{tom}
\NewPerson{frodo}
\NewPerson{Gandalf}



\begin{document}
\section{In the supermarket}
\DisplayPersons
\tomx{Hi, I'm Tom!}

\frodox{Hi, I'm Frodo!}

\section{At TeX.SE}

\DisplayPersons

\frodox{Hi, I'm Frodo!}

\frodox{I am going to Mordor}

\Gandalfx{Cast the ring into the fire!}

\tomx{Waiting for Godot}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update with hightlighting**

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \g_luke_listofpersons_seq
\seq_new:N \l_luke_listofpersons_seq 


\NewDocumentCommand{\addperson}{m}{%
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_luke_listofpersons_seq {#1}
  \seq_gremove_duplicates:N \g_luke_listofpersons_seq
}


\NewDocumentCommand{\addpersonlocal}{m}{%
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \l_luke_listofpersons_seq {#1}
}

\cs_new:Npn \IfPersonCalledAlreadyF #1#2 {%
  \seq_if_in:NnF \l_luke_listofpersons_seq {#1} {#2}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\DisplayPersons}{}{%
  \seq_clear:N \l_luke_listofpersons_seq
  \group_begin:
  \seq_clear:N \l_tmpa_seq
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_luke_listofpersons_seq {%
    \IfRefUndefinedExpandable{##1\thesection}{}{
      \seq_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {\use:c{##1h}}
     }
   }
   \seq_if_empty:NF \l_tmpa_seq {
     \PrePersonList
     \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {,~} 
     \PostPersonList
   }
   \group_end:

}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\PostPersonList}{}{%
  \bigskip%

}

\NewDocumentCommand{\displayindividualperson}{m}{%
  \textbf{#1}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\PrePersonList}{}{%
  {\large \bfseries Persons in Section \thesection}

}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\NewPerson}{m+m}{%
  % Add this person to the global list
  \addperson{#1}%
  % Now define the personal \...x command 
  \expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\csname #1x\endcsname{+m}{%
    %Check if the person has been called in the local section already
    \IfPersonCalledAlreadyF{#1}{%
      \addpersonlocal{#1}
      % Add the personal to the local list, i.e. per section
      % Check whether the label has been defined already
        \protected@edef\@currentlabel{\thesection.#1}\label{#1\thesection}
    }%
    \textsc{#1:} ##1%
  }% End of the \...x command
  \expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\csname #1h\endcsname{}{%
    #2{#1}%
  }
}% End of \NewPerson
\makeatother


\NewPerson{tom}{\colorbox{green}}
\NewPerson{frodo}{\colorbox{yellow}}
\NewPerson{Gandalf}{\fcolorbox{yellow}{yellow!60!blue}}



\begin{document}
\section{In the supermarket}
\DisplayPersons
\tomx{Hi, I'm Tom!}

\frodox{Hi, I'm Frodo!}

\section{At TeX.SE}

\DisplayPersons

\frodox{Hi, I'm Frodo!}

\frodox{I am going to Mordor}

\Gandalfx{Cast the ring into the fire!}

\tomx{Waiting for Godot}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Huge thanks! I'll give that a try! Wouldn't have known how to approach that...

Comment: I will update with a better version...

Comment: New persons should be added before `\begin{document}`, in my point of view

Comment: Yes, all Persons are added before `\begin{document}`, but it's nice that you added the ability to add persons inline :) When compiled with `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode`, the character names only appear on every second compile time. Is that expected behaviour?

Comment: @LukeLR: As with any label approach, you need compile twice. The labels are written to the `.aux` first, which is then read at the begin of the second call, then positions, names etc. are known document-wide

Comment: Yes, but that's not what I meant. When I compile the first time, the `.aux` gets written. It's clear that lists will be missing at the first compile time. At the second compile time, all lists appear as expected. But when compiled for the third time, even without having made any changes, the character lists disappear in the output again. This makes me wonder, as e.g. `tableofcontents` does not disappear on every odd compile time.

Comment: @LukeLR: My checks were too paranoid. Try the updated version

Comment: Yes, that works! Thanks a lot! One last question: Usually I use commands like `\<charactername>h` to output the characternames, for example to dynamically enable highlighting. I understand that the output of the character names is defined in `displayindividualperson`, but how can I tell the macro to use `\<charactername>h` to output the charactername? I see that you've done something similiar in `\expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\csname #1x\endcsname{+m}{` to define the `\<charactername>x` command, but I don't how I can use that to call the `\<charactername>h`-command...

Comment: @LukeLR: I replaced `\displayindividualperson` with `\use:c{##1h}` which looks for `\tomh` or `\frodoh` etc. If is not present, nothing is shown. I added a parameter to `\NewPerson` which is used to define `\fooh` etc. and will grab the argument. It, your command to highlight must be a macro that expects the name as the last argument. See the examples

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think everything works now! Huge thanks for your efforts!

Comment: @LukeLR: You're welcome. Viele Grüße und viel Spaß beim TeXen ;-)

Comment: Vielen Dank! Viele Grüße zurück! ;-) (You're Welcome)