# How to make \NewDocumentCommand global?

Tags: macros, grouping

I'm using a custom macros as suggested by Christian Hupfer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357020/latex-output-custom-commands-used-in-current-section) to create characters for typesetting a drama script:

```
\makeatletter
    \NewDocumentCommand{\NewPerson}{m}{%
      \expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\csname #1x\endcsname{+m}{%
        #1: \textbf{##1}\par%
      }
      \expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\csname #1h\endcsname{}{%
        \textsc{#1}%
      }
    }
\makeatother
```

When called like this:

```
\NewPerson{thomas}
```

everything works fine, the macros `\thomash` and `\thomasx` are available in the entire document. But when called from within a group, like this:

```
{
\NewPerson{thomas}
}
```

both macros are only accessible from within the group. How can I define those macros in such a manner that they may be used outside the group? I've read about prepending `\global` to the command definitions inside `\NewPerson`, but that didn't fix the issue. A MWE could be:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter
    \NewDocumentCommand{\NewPerson}{m}{%
      \expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\csname #1x\endcsname{+m}{%
        #1: \textbf{##1}\par%
      }
      \expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\csname #1h\endcsname{}{%
        \textsc{#1}%
      }
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\NewPerson{thomas}
\thomasx{asdf}
\thomash

{
\NewPerson{elvis}
\elvisx{asdf}
\elvish
}

\elvisx{asdf}
\elvish

\end{document}
```

Here, using `\elvisx` and `\elvish` outside the group doesn't work. Any ideas on how to fix that are very appreciated!

Comment: Well, you don't need `\makeatletter...\makeatother` here...

Comment: See documenation of `xparse`: **The xparse package provides a high-level interface for producing document-level commands** -- So just use `\gdef` or somthing similar inside your definition.

Comment: As others noted: Your choice of syntax is odd. Did you over-simplify to make the MWE? I assume that is why the `\makeat` commands. But there is no reason to need `xparse` or `\NewDocumentCommand` for what you are trying to do.

Comment: The `\NewPerson` macro was never intended to be used in a group.

Comment: `\NewDocumentCommand` is intended for commands with document scope (there is a clue in the name)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes, I know, it was not intended to be used in a group. I just didn't expect this to make a difference :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either use `\expandafter\gdef\csname #1x\endcsname##1{...}` or remain in the `expl3` domain which is the ground of `xparse`, saying `\cs_gset:cpn`.

In order to prevent the gobbling of spaces etc. in the `\ExplSyntaxOn...\ExplSyntaxOff` domain, I've defined format wrappers (or 'hooks'), which is a good way if the style of the speech etc. formatting should be changed later on.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\personspeechformater}{m+m}{%
  #1: \textbf{#2}\par%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\personhighlighter}{m}{%
  \textsc{#1}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\NewPerson}{m}{%
  \cs_gset:cpn  {#1x} ##1{\personspeechformater{#1}{##1}}%
  \cs_gset:cpn  {#1h} {\personhighlighter{#1}}%
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

% With \gdef



\NewDocumentCommand{\NewOtherPerson}{m}{%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname #1x\endcsname##1{\personspeechformater{#1}{##1}}%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname #1h\endcsname{\personhighlighter{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}
\NewPerson{thomas}
\thomasx{asdf}
\thomash

{
  \NewPerson{elvis}
  \elvisx{asdf}
  \elvish
}


\elvisx{asdf}
\elvish


{
  \NewOtherPerson{Gandalf}
}


\Gandalfx{Foo}
\Gandalfh
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Extending and improving Christian's fine answer, I suggest adding something. A character's name might have diacritics that make it impossible directly using the name in command names.

I also added a rudimentary way for keeping track of the names.

Note that `\cs_new:Npn` acts globally and also checks whether the command is not already defined.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \g_lukelr_persons_seq
\prop_new:N \g_lukelr_persons_prop

\NewDocumentCommand{\NewPerson}{O{#2}m}
 {
  \cs_new:cpn {#1x} ##1 { \speech { #2 } { ##1 } }
  \cs_new:cpn {#1h} { \mention { #2 } }
  % list of keys for persons
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_lukelr_persons_seq { #1 }
  % correspondence between keys and persons
  \prop_gput:Nnn \g_lukelr_persons_prop { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\ListPersons}{}
 {
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_lukelr_persons_seq
   {
    \prop_item:Nn \g_lukelr_persons_prop { ##1 } \par
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\speech}{ m +m }{%
  #1: {\bfseries #2}\par
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\mention}{ m }{%
  \textsc{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\NewPerson{Treemunch}
{\NewPerson[Ooc]{Ööç}} % in a group just for testing

Scene 1: \Treemunchh\ and \Ooch

\Treemunchx{Here I am.}
\Oocx{Why are you so late?}

\bigskip

\ListPersons

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, initially, for the other solution I had some 'complex' solution in mind, but I did not want to fire with the loaded weapon of `expl3` to achieve something what you did here.

Answer (score 2):

I have written a function `\GNewDocumentCommand` which has the same signature as `\NewDocumentCommand` and almost the same semantics, except the new command is defined globally. I've also written analogous versions for the `Renew`, `Provide`, and `Declare` variants.

One way to use these functions is to paste the following code into a new file `xparse-global.tex`, place this file in the TeX engine's search path, and then import the code into your working TeX document thus: `\input xparse-global`. You must also import the `xparse` package with `\usepackage`. It doesn't matter if `xparse` is imported before or after `xparse-global`. Alternatively, you can create a LaTeX2e package from this code and import it with `\usepackage`.

```
\input expl3-generic
\ExplSyntaxOn
\group_begin:

\cs_set_protected:Npn \__xparse_global_new:NN #1#2
{
    \cs_new_protected:Npn #2 ##1##2##3
    {
        #1 ##1 {##2} {##3}
        \cs_gset_eq:NN ##1 ##1

        % The following couple of lines make use of xparse's internals,
        % namely the implementation of \...DocumentCommand's "return value".
        \cs_gset_eq:cc { \cs_to_str:N ##1 ~ } { \cs_to_str:N ##1 ~ }
        \cs_gset_eq:cc { \cs_to_str:N ##1 ~code } { \cs_to_str:N ##1 ~code }
    }
}

\clist_set:Nn \l__variants_clist { New, Renew, Provide, Declare }
\clist_map_variable:NNn \l__variants_clist \l__variant_str
{
    \str_set:Nx \l__local_func_name_str { \l__variant_str DocumentCommand }
    \str_set:Nx \l__global_func_name_str { G \l__local_func_name_str }

    \exp_args:Ncc \__xparse_global_new:NN
        { \l__local_func_name_str }
        { \l__global_func_name_str }
}

\group_end:
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

My code depends on the implementation of `\NewDocumentCommand` and its siblings by the `xparse` source code, so it may break if this implementation is changed in the future. It'll be nice if the LaTeX3 folks can incorporate my code into the `xparse` package and keep it in sync with future modifications of this package.

---

Now your minimal example can be rewritten as follows. One line was added and two more were slightly modified. See comments below.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{xparse}
% This line was added
\input xparse-global

\makeatletter
    \NewDocumentCommand{\NewPerson}{m}{%
      % This line was modified: \NewDocumentCommand -> \GNewDocumentCommand
      \expandafter\GNewDocumentCommand\csname #1x\endcsname{+m}{%
        #1: \textbf{##1}\par%
      }
      % This line was modified: \NewDocumentCommand -> \GNewDocumentCommand
      \expandafter\GNewDocumentCommand\csname #1h\endcsname{}{%
        \textsc{#1}%
      }
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\NewPerson{thomas}
\thomasx{asdf}
\thomash

{
\NewPerson{elvis}
\elvisx{asdf}
\elvish
}

\elvisx{asdf}
\elvish

\end{document}
```

This compiles successfully and typesets as follows.

[image: OP's minimal example rewritten with my global versions of exparse's functions]

---

P.S. Your minimal example contains an un-manifested bug. To fix it, either replace `+m` by `m`, or replace `\textbf{##1}` by `\begin{bfseries}##1\end{bfseries}`.

Comment: Evan acknowledges this in their answer but just to emphasise for anyone unfamiliar with expl3: the internals of xparse are very much subject to change over time and so this code may very well no longer work if it is not updated accordingly... in expl3 code a `\__` prefix to a command indicates that it is internal to the package and stability should not be expected.

Comment: @WillRobertson: Actually all the `\__` variables and functions I used are my own. The part that depends on the `xparse` implementation consists of the three consecutive lines that start with `\cs_gset_eq:NN`. What they do is they make global three functions used internally by the "return value" of `\NewDocumentCommand`.

Comment: @EvanAad The standard with local private variables (in case you intend to follow, just to leave it here in case someone reads the answer) is `\l__..` rather than `\__l_..`, IIRC.

Comment: @Manuel: Thanks. What about private functions?

Comment: @EvanAad Yes, private functions since have no scope `\l__`, `\g__`, `\c__`, just start with `\__`.

Comment: @EvanAad — exactly; at some point in the future xparse may will change, rename, or remove `\__xparse_global_new:NN` and then your code will no longer work :)

Comment: @WillRobertson: My code may break if the `xparse` implementation changes, but not because of the `\__xparse_global_new:NN` function, because it is defined locally. This is the beauty and power of true local variables, a power that the LaTeX3 language should strive to guarantee for variables of all data types.

Comment: @EvanAad — apologies, I misread your code while I was in a rush this morning. You’re right — it’s only the internals you are referencing that would change.

Comment: This already breaks. I believe changing xparse to cmd can fix it https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/508001/keyboard-tab-character-in-argument-v-xparse/632687#comment1577740_632687