# SageTeX does not work when TABs are used as indents

Tags: pdftex, formatting, python, sourcecode, sagetex

I wrote two practically identical files that use `SageTeX` to determine whether a positive integer is odd or even. The first example uses tabs for indentation.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\begin{document}
\begin{sagesilent}
def oddeven(n):
    if n % 2:
        return "ODD"
    else:
        return "EVEN"
\end{sagesilent}
$3$ is $\sagestr{oddeven(3)}$.

$16$ is $\sagestr{oddeven(16)}$.
\end{document}
```

Output:

```
3 is ??.
16 is ??.
```

Somewhere in the logs:

```
File "/sagetex_with_tabs.sagetex.sage.py", line 14
    if n % _sage_const_2 :
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

If I change each tab to four spaces, the code compiles without issues and works as expected.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\begin{document}
\begin{sagesilent}
def oddeven(n):
    if n % 2:
        return "ODD"
    else:
        return "EVEN"
\end{sagesilent}
$3$ is $\sagestr{oddeven(3)}$.

$16$ is $\sagestr{oddeven(16)}$.
\end{document}
```

Output:

```
3 is ODD.
16 is EVEN.
```

I have never had issues using tabs for indentation in both `Python` and `LaTeX`. It feels very weird that `SageTeX` does not recognize tabs as a valid method of indentation. How do I get it to recognize tabs?

The following `Python` code works just fine even though it uses tabs:

```python
def oddeven(n):
    if n % 2:
        return "ODD"
    else:
        return "EVEN"
print("3 is {}.".format(oddeven(3)))
print("16 is {}.".format(oddeven(16)))
```

p.s. Both tex files were compiled in the following order: pdflatex -> sage -> pdflatex

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: When I copied/pasted your code into [Cocalc](https://cocalc.com/), everything compiled without error. However, a search of this site gives your problem [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/663697/sagetex-ignores-indents-if-they-are-done-in-tabs-insteads-of-spaces-how-to-mak) with a proposed solution. Perhaps this is a problem in an earlier version of Sage/sagetex which has been patched in later versions? You might try checking if proposed solution works for you. If not, maybe updating your system will fix it?

Comment: I know little about Sage TeX, but I'm very suspicious of the percent sign in the line `if n % 2:` .  Percent by default begins a comment, so if it hasn't been changed, everything in that line after `n` will be ignored.  Please check.

Comment: The % sign is in a `sagesilent` block. This is okay, the environment is Python there and comments require #. In Python, n % 2 is giving us n mod 2.